# Stronger version of maximum modulus theorem with increasing path

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The maximum modulus theorem states that for any non-constant holomorphic function $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ defined over an open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, the map $|f|$ cannot have a local maximum. Then, for any $x \in U$, can we find a path $p : [0,1] \to U$ with $p(0) = x$ and such that the function $|f \circ p|$ is strictly increasing?
This seems true. An holomorphic function looks locally like the map $x \mapsto x^n$, and is a ramified covering map onto its image, so we should be able to lift a path simply from the image, but I'm not sure how to do it rigorously.

I would also be interested to know if the following seemingly stronger result is true: there is a continuous map $p : [0,+\infty[ \to U$ with $p(0) = x$, such that $|f \circ p|$ is strictly increasing and such that for any compact subset $K \subseteq U$, the set $p^{-1}(K)$ is bounded. Perhaps it is a consequence of the previous property, but I don't see how to construct it: just extending the function over and over again (even with transfinite induction) doesn't always give a function verifying the last condition. For example, taking $f = \mathrm{id}$, beginning at $0$ we could have a path spiraling wildly without ever leaving the unit disk, and wsuch that all the points of the unit circle are accumulation points of the image, so we couldn't extend it further.

I ask just by curiosity.